# AngularJS not loading views in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I'm venturing my first try in AngularJS world. I'm using `ui-router` with some states. Google Chrome is loading the states without any problem while Firefox just doesn't respond. Firebug doesn't even show any stack, just an error without anything.

[image: Firebug screenshot]

Here is the state:

```
.state('showads', {
        url: "/ads",
        templateUrl: "views/ads/index.html",
        controller: "AdsIndexController",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'App',
                    files: [
                        'js/controllers/AdsControllers.js',
                        'js/services/AdService.js',
                    ]
                }]);
            }]
        }
    })
```

Comment: The very tiny image shows the problem to be an HTTP related one. It is unable to get your template file. Try removing the leading '/' maybe? So "/views/ads/index.html" will be "views/ads/index.html"

Comment: @SirDemon I'm sorry for the tiny image, but you can open it in a new tab, it's in a big resolution. I know that it can't load the file. I tried with or without the '/'. It works perfectly in chrome but not in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I'm using µblock, an extension to block ads, and it's blocking the request because the name of the file is ads.html.